# Problem to work jquery code in Datatables responsive

Tags: jquery, datatables

I create a datatable with [DataTables](http://datatables.net) and my datatable has 29 columns. When I select responsive true and create last column of rows a button to show a dialog, button not work but when I set button in first column of rows its work!

My jquery file:

```
(function ($) {

    $('button').on('click', function () {
        alert('WOHOOO Work');
     })

    $('table').DataTable( {
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    buttons: [
        'copy', 'excel', 'print',
    ],
    responsive: true,
} );

})(jQuery);
```

When I cleck responsive button (+), jquery build a `<tr class="child">`, and my code not work because in first of load page my button not build. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
$('button').on('click', function () {
    alert('WOHOOO Work');
 });
```

Try the following code:

```
$(document).on("click", ".child", function() {
    alert("added button clicked");
});
```

Comment: Not work. with this code when I click on my page alert show!

Comment: sorry about that. It should be without the `$()` I have edited my answer.

Comment: You can read about event delegation here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
$(document).on('click', ('.child button.btn-class'), function() {
    alert('WOHOOO Work');
});
```

This work in your button that has "btn.class" class.